# How do you get paths of copied files from clipboard?

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to retrieve paths of files and folders currently copied into the clipboard, is this possible in C#?

So let's say I do Ctrl + C a folder. That folder will go to clipboard, I need a way to extract the path to that folder. Same goes for copied files.

I'm developing a file server, I already can send files and folders: all I need is to provide a list of paths to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft supplies some samples about it:

Have a look at: [DragDropOpenTextFile](https://github.com/microsoft/WPF-Samples/tree/master/Drag%20and%20Drop/DragDropOpenTextFile)

This is the method used to check it there is a file copied in the clipboard:

```cs
// If the data object in args is a single file, this method will return the filename.
// Otherwise, it returns null.
private string IsSingleFile(DragEventArgs args)
{
    // Check for files in the hovering data object.
    if (args.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop, true))
    {
        var fileNames = args.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
        // Check for a single file or folder.
        if (fileNames?.Length is 1)
        {
            // Check for a file (a directory will return false).
            if (File.Exists(fileNames[0]))
            {
                // At this point we know there is a single file.
                return fileNames[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You get a DragEventArgs from the Drop event handler of your control.

```cs
private void EhDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs args)
{
    // Mark the event as handled, so Control's native Drop handler is not called.
    args.Handled = true;

    var fileName = IsSingleFile(args);
    if (fileName != null)
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry dude, that's not what I was looking for. I don't need to get files that have been dropped off, I needed to get files when you press ctrl+v on the window. I've achieved that with Clipboard class.

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it to work myself, `Clipboard.GetFileDropList()` gets you both files and folders paths, what a neat little function!

```
var unparsedFilesList = Clipboard.GetFileDropList();
foreach(var filePath in unparsedFilesList)
{
   MessageBox.Show(filePath);
}
```